# How do I create a Prosthetics?

Tags: discussion

I posted [How do I de-construct a model created by someone else?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245219/how-do-i-de-construct-a-model-created-by-someone-else) two days ago.  That post was closed.  I edited the original post to explain that this was for a prosthetic finger.  That post remains closed.

Prosthetics are important to those who have lost part of a limb.

Is there a way to have a post re-opened?

---

The .stl and .blend files can be downloaded from https://temp.foxping.com/

Comment: what did you mean by "how do I remove the internals"? Are there some inner vertices in the mesh? is it the problem you are trying to fix? Maybe share your file

Comment: Hi ttom "*Is there a way to have a post re-opened?*" Certainly, post are reopened when the original close reasons are solved. Could you please clarify in detail what your issue is, and what you are trying to achieve, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above the question. Don't post as a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: The preferred way, I believe, to share files is to post them on blend-exchange. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Hi, the url Blend-Exchange is asking for is your [*original question*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245219/how-do-i-de-construct-a-model-created-by-someone-else), which once edited and made more clear as requested will be put up for review to be reopened.

Comment: I've posted the same question about prosthetics two times. It has been closed / migrated both times. Should I post a third time?  If so, where should I post it?  Uploading a file has no value as both post have been closed.

Comment: Please just edit the [original question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245219/how-do-i-de-construct-a-model-created-by-someone-else) on the main site. As has already been said, "closed "is not a permanent state so long as edits are made that make a question answerable and clear (or on-topic in other cases) Reposting will only create a duplicate which may get closed again, which would not be helpful for you.

Comment: I don't know what to change. The intent is to create a prosthetic. What else is needed?